# How to use a javascript function inside a dust.js template?

Tags: data-binding, templating, dust.js, client-side-templating, templating-engine

I'm using dust.js to do a client side templating. I would like to use a javascript function in my template, the function would get it's argument during templating i.e

Ex:

```
mytemplate = " <span> Hi getName({id}) </span>"
myjson = { id : 1 }
```

In this case, both the template and json-data are sent from server and templating happens on client side.

In the above example, I would get the 'id' from json data and want to display the name of user corresponding to that id.

I'm new to templating. I would like to know how this can be done using dust.js.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with Dust.js by creating a script block within your template:

```
{! Dust template !}
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userName = getName('{id|s|J');
  // Do whatever you want with the username
</script>
```

Note, the `|s|j`, which is important for security filtering.

In your particular use case, however, it would probably be better to just send the user's name and id in the JSON:

```
{! Dust template !}
  <span id="user-{id}"> Hi {name} </span>

// JSON
{
  id: 1,
  name: smfoote
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) My case is a lot more complex situation and I think using a script block inside the template should solve my problem.